# OBS Studio Screen, Still Comes Black When I Running Under Xorg

Tags: 18.04, drivers, screen, opengl, obs-studio

After a Days I Wanted To Stream My Gaming To Youtube, But I Got A Problem: My OBS Screen is Black

I have tried this:

- I Have Checked My Ubuntu Session, That Won't running Under WayLand, And Its On Xorg:

  ```
  WaylandEnable=false
  ```
- I Have Also Tried To Check My OpenGL Driver Is Installed Or Not, But Hopefully It Installed & Working Properly:

  ```
  $ glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
  OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 20.0.4
  ```

I Don't Know Actually What Is My Problem! I Tried Every Solutions, But It Won't Work At All!

But Unexpectly My VokoScreen Works Very Well, I Don't Know Actually What Is My Problem With OBS Studio?

Why OBS Screen Is Still Black?

Comment: can you please share was it working earlier.  mine is also Xorg and OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 19.2.8. mine is working perfect. Do you have problem in configuring how to record.

Answer (score 0):

Follow steps:

1. Open `obs`.
2. In "scenes" tab on right bottom of screen. press "+" sign and select "Screen Recorder".
3. In "Sources" tab next to "scenes" tab press "+" sign and select "Windows capture(Xcomposite)". and double click on this.
4. Now a properties widow will open. Here you can select the desired window like web browser or LibreOffice or desktop (which is already open) to record.

Hop this will help you.

Comment: thank you, but didnt help, there is still a problem with driver, i've added the source display, but now fixed, with additional driver addons, added nvidia display and fixed.